Missing few Cookies (Only in Chrome browser) in the First-Party Site's Request Header When Redirecting (Status Code: 303) from a Third-Party Site

Chrome Browser Version: 126.0.6478.127 (Official Build) (arm64)

Used technologies:

ClientSide - Html, React.js, Javascript
ServerSide - GoLang

What I tried:
Step 1:
Setting a few cookies with values using javascript and using SameSite and Secure policies upon landing on the first-party site. Added cookies, for example:
Cookie A = 'value 1'
Cookie B = 'value 2'
Cookie C = 'value 3'


Step 2:
Performing OAuth login with Microsoft/Google (third-party sites) to authenticate the user.
Step 3:
After authenticating, a redirection occurs from the respective third-party site to the first-party site. The referrer in the request header is the third-party site. Due to this, the Chrome browser does not set the cookies in the request header, which handles the user login with those cookies (Cookie A, Cookie B, Cookie C). When reading those cookies from the server side, not all the cookies are available. Randomly, one or two cookies are missing.
Chrome has restricted third-party cookies by default for 1% of Chrome Stable clients and 20% of Canary, Dev and Beta clients
Ref: https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd
Will restricted third-party cookies affect the flow or not? If not, what could be the possible root cause of the issue and the possible better solution for this?
I appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance.

"using SameSite" - set to which value?

Default for SameSite, when you don't specify it, is Lax.

I don't understand how you "handle the user login".  (1) Your first-party site must receive some kind of assertion from the third-party site, how is that done? (2) Does the redirection happen via GET or POST request? In the POST case, cookies would be sent only if they have SameSite=None. In the GET case, they would be sent unless they have SameSite=Strict.
